# Domestic wifi Network Management

Tags: wifi, networking, router

I've got an issue with my home Wifi network. I get 300mbps on my ISP modem:

4 Gigabyte ports and Wifi N

There is an Xbox One (Wifi N) on the ground floor

I've got 1 desktop with Wifi AC and 2 other computers with Wifi N on the 1st floor.

And the issue is that I cannot benefit from my fiber optic connection to it's full potential.

On my PC with wifi ac card i get about 25mbps, on the other computers/laptop it's about 18-20mbps. On the Xbox which is the nearest device to the modem (~20m apart) I get a 40-45mbps.

I want to invest about 100euros and setup a network though Wifi (preferably but not limited to) that can let my xbox and PC get atleast a 100mbps (seperately in the best case).

Is there a Wifi router or a pair of PLC adapters that can manage that?

I've looked into Cat6 ethernet cable (pretty cheap) but it's a real pain to setup and ruins the looks.

---

So I'm looking into home plugs but the ones that give acceptable speed are pretty costly (as expected), and for the wifi part I've come across some Xiaomi routers that are WifiAC capable that costs about 30bucks but unfortunalety there are no reviews on them to see their actual speed.

Comment: Looks like you've got interference. What is your home made of? It'll also be helpful to know the model of your router.

Comment: It's pretty old (about 20-30years minimum) so no clue in what was used in the walls.
And for the Modem it's Neufbox SFR. it's a pretty standard crappy general purpose modem (I get a maximum of 50mbps while my laptop (wifi n) is litterally on top of it).

Comment: Wait a minute, you *did* do a proper connection speedtest (for example, speedtest.net) right? A 200Mbits/sec homeplug will deliver a speed of around 20MB/s. Please perform an Internet speed test with [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net) and insert a screenshot in your question.

Comment: I did run a proper speed test on seedtest.net. i do not have the screen shot on me right now, but trust me on wired connection i get 37.4MB/s that's 300mbps. the 200mbps homeplug was just like everyother product in the market, THEORETICAL. My wifi is supposed to give me 300mbps since it's 'N' but i put my laptop on top of the box and i get a crappy 50mbps. the wifi provided by the ISP modem/router is bad. I need something more powerfull or a better homeplug, caus if a 200mbps delivers 25mbps, then i'd need a 2.4gbps homeplug to get the full 300mbps, that's how bad the signal quality is.

Comment: The homeplug connects via Ethernet, not WiFi. Are you sure you're using the correct product?

Comment: My wifi N gives me max of 50mbps and 25mbps in my room, my homeplug in my room gets me 25mbps. There's no difference in speed between them from my room, they're equally crappy.
it doesn't matter if the homeplug is gigabyte ethernet or 100mps ethernet or not, it's connection speed is crappy inbetween the homeplugs so the issue remains. I need a better homeplug under 100bucks that can get me atleast 100mbps (real) in my room or a wifi solution that can get me that speed in my room.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've a fair amount of experience with homeplug - I'm not going to recommend specific models since I have *no* clue if the sinoji plugs I use are available elsewhere or are the best option outside my current market. Wirecutter seems to like [zyxel](http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-powerline-networking-kit/) at the moment and are a good place for up to date reviews.

I'd suggest getting homeplug 500 or better gear if you want 100mbps. *Typically* the advertised speed is for the *whole* network, and you never ever get line speed over homeplug. I have homeplug 1800 gear at the moment. Its got better noise rejection and reliability, even if realworld speeds are ~300mbps. They do work fantastically for me though.

Stuff to look for? homeplug units *must* be plugged directly into a socket, no powerstrips. Get passthrough models, and plug a powerstrip to that instead. Passthrough models also filter noise. Wallwarts and other SMPS devices produce *some* noise that may affect signal quality, so plug them into a passthrough or a powerstrip on an extension cord.

If you get cutouts - it might be due to a powerful motor like a washing machine. Move the homeplug unit.

As for wifi, I currently have a 2 AP setup. If I was doing it again, I'd pick up "professional" grade APs - we used to have ubiquity APs in my last workplace and they were *fantastic*, with easy management. Ars technica has an in depth review of the current models [here](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/10/review-ubiquiti-unifi-made-me-realize-how-terrible-consumer-wi-fi-gear-is/). They are 'pure' APs so you can hook them into your current router. I'd probably end up with a 3pack, hooked into more homeplug units or directly into a (better) router.

Features like heatmaps and the way they handle clients are far ahead of most consumer routers. At a certain level of complexity, these give you more options and *information* to optimise your network.

Comment: Wonderful. I'll try to find them in France, I can see they're on a discount in US so maybe i'll buy from there if the port is cheap. :D
anyways thanks a lot

Comment: Make sure its for the correct voltage and plug type.

Comment: I can't see what this adds that my answer doesn't cover, besides the *no powerstrips*.

Comment: And to consider professional grade APs, and that sometimes washing machines interfere with homeplug devices, and some degree of specifics over the speeds I get, and why 'faster' homeplug standards may be better despite the advertised speeds never being reached and....

Comment: @JourneymanGeek 'Your router is too close to other appliances`, `Could simply be that you need a new router` (not entirely 'professional grade AP').

Comment: I've added a bit of information on why I would pick these APs. Also, the washing machine thing is something specific to homeplug, and is worth knowing. There's a clear difference in focus in our answers which is why I decided to write a seperate one rather than commenting or editing.

Answer (score 4):

**Looks like you've got some interference somewhere.** This can happen for a variety of reasons.

---

**Bad placement of router**

Radio waves cannot easily travel through granite and other certain materials walls are made of, and your WiFi signal could suffer from degradation if your walls are made of one of these materials. A solution to this would be one (or more) of the following:

- Purchase a couple of signal boosters, and place them where WiFi signal is low;
- Use a home-plug (aka, powerline adapter)- get a dual-pack so you can plug-in both your Xbox & PC. This works by sending the Ethernet connection via your home's wiring- be sure to get a Gigabit set.
- Could simply be that you need a new router. This is often the case where the router is supplied by the ISP, as these are mostly low-quality routers that are not able to properly handle 'serious' Internet

So **yes** a pair of powerline adapters (I assume that's what 'PLC' refers to) *may* do the trick, but then it may not (see below).

---

**Your router is too close to other appliances**

This links to the previous point, but a router could be suitably placed but be too near other appliances, for example a microwave. If your router is too close to another appliance, move it to a location where there are no appliances nearby.

---

**Your router & another router are sharing the same WiFi channel**

To fix, change the WiFi channel by logging into your router's web interface & changing it appropriately. If you know how to use WiFi analyser programs, you can see which channel is free (if any) and then change the channel to that.

Routers on the same WiFi channel create digital noise (dBA), and will cause problems with speed, packet loss, etc.

---

**It might not be your WiFi at all**

Connect your desktop or Xbox directly to the router via Ethernet, and then run a connection speed test (*ensure WiFi is switched off on the Xbox so the Xbox doesn't connect to the router via WiFi!*). If it is much faster than WiFi, then you've got a problem with the wireless environment or the router itself (see above). If it is the same speed as WiFi, you've got a problem with the router or your ISP.

Comment: PLC is what we call CPL here or homeplug as you say it. I've used the homeplug solution (200mbps as per advertisement) I got the same result as the wifi as in a mediocre 25mbps.
My router is unfortunately not movable. The fibre optic port is installed there and thus restricting me from moving it around.
there is a fridge and a washing machine nearby other than that it's pretty much the only electronic (Waves producing) device so the only interference I think is the walls materials.

Comment: For the channel interference I used an android app that scans existing wifi signals to choose the best possible channel.
As for the last part I'm sure of that it's the wifi, First thing I did when I got router working was try the internet speed through gigabyte ethernet port and that's where I got the 300mbps, updated nvidia drivers at 37MB/s (nerdgasm).